# Grammar of Birchot HaShachar

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk, shacharis-morning-prayer

I have at times noticed that there are disagreements in the grammar of certain brachot in Birchot haShachar. For example, the first brachah is "אשר נתן", one of the later ones is either (depending on custom) "אשר הכין" or "המכין", and the last short one is always "הנותן". From my limited knowledge of Hebrew grammar, these conjugations do not agree. I find that many read these brachot as a litany, which brings to mind the idea of grammatical agreement. If it makes any difference, my main siddurim are the Rödelheims, Koren, and Rinat Yisrael, all of which are Nusach Ashkenaz. However, I have also noticed this in assorted Edot Hamizrach and Sephard siddurim.

Why does the grammar of the different brachot not agree?

Comment: Fwiw I've seen/heard "הנותן" for the first ברכה.

Comment: @msh210, I've seen one reference to a particular chassidus using it in their nusach, but I've never seen it in a siddur or heard it from a sha"tz.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, until further editing occurs per @DoubleAA's suggestion. Just a hunch that you may have some other ideas to add to "flavor" your question.

The first bracha starts אשר נתן as it is clear that it is in the past. The rooster crowed, already, and that was your "alarm clock" to arise and serve Hash-m.

Comment: Question edited. No other ideas at present for the question, but someone who has ideas could certainly add their own.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in the מחזור מכל השנה מנהג פולין the text of the first ברכה is הנותן not אשר נתן and the text of the "later" one is המכין.
However, in Rav Schwab on Prayer, he says that the first bracha is in agreement with a posuk in iyov, I'll edit it in later. The last bracha is in agreement with a posuk in tehillim, this will also be edited in later.